Universal motivic measures for singular varieties
Consider a field $K$ of characteristic zero and the category $\text{Var}_K$ of varieties over $K$. We're interested in the Grothendieck ring of varieties $K_0(\text{Var}_K)$ and the concept of motivic measures - ring homomorphisms $$\mu: K_0(\text{Var}_K) \to R$$ for some ring $R$.
For smooth projective varieties, we're familiar with the motivic measure induced by the Hodge structure:
$$\mu_{\text{Hodge}}(X) = \sum_{p,q} (-1)^{p+q} h^{p,q}(X) u^p v^q \in \mathbb{Z}[u,v]$$
where $h^{p,q}(X)$ are the Hodge numbers of $X$. But what about a measure that works for all varieties, including singular ones? Does there exist a "universal motivic measure"
$$\mu_{\text{univ}}: K_0(\text{Var}_K) \to R_{\text{univ}}$$ for some ring $R_{\text{univ}}$? Ideally, this measure would satisfy:

For smooth projective $X$, there's a ring homomorphism $\phi: R_{\text{univ}} \to \mathbb{Z}[u,v]$ with $\phi(\mu_{\text{univ}}(X)) = \mu_{\text{Hodge}}(X)$.
For singular $Y$, $\mu_{\text{univ}}(Y)$ encodes a "virtual Hodge structure" compatible with resolution of singularities.
$\mu_{\text{univ}}$ allows for "motivic integration", computing $\mu_{\text{univ}}(Y)$ for singular $Y$ via a resolution $f: X \to Y$.

What if we take $R_{\text{univ}}$ to be $\mathbb{Z}[[x_1, x_2, \ldots]]$, the ring of formal power series in countably many variables? For smooth projective $X$, we could define:
$$\mu_{\text{univ}}(X) = \sum_{p,q} (-1)^{p+q} h^{p,q}(X) x_p x_q$$
The challenge seems to be with singular varieties. Given a resolution $f: \tilde{Y} \to Y$ with exceptional divisor $E$, we might try something like:
$$\mu_{\text{univ}}(Y) = \mu_{\text{univ}}(\tilde{Y}) - \mu_{\text{univ}}(E) + C(f)$$
where $C(f)$ are correction terms accounting for the change in cohomology.

The universal motivic measure is, tautologically, the identity map to $K_0$ itself. If you want a universal motivic measure which satisfies some further relations then you quotient $K_0$ by those relations. Of course this isn't all that useful.

@QiaochuYuan: Thanks. What about the Grothendieck ring $K_0(\text{Var}_K)$? It has some pathological properties ) e.g it is not a domain in characteristic 0 which limits the types of measures we can use.

Perhaps you already know this: By Bittner's theorem, $K_0({\rm Var}_K$ is isomorphic to the ring generated by smooth projective varieties modulo relations $[X] - [Z] = [{\rm Bl}_Z(X)] - [E]$ where $Z\subseteq X$ is a smooth closed subvariety and $E\subseteq {\rm Bl}_Z(X)$ is its preimage in the blowup. It follows that every motivic measure on smooth projective varieties (satisfying the blowup relation) extends uniquely to a motivic measure on all varieties, satisfying the scissor relations. So in particular the Hodge polynomial extends uniquely, giving the virtual Hodge polynomial.
